# How to change the columns which include the highest and lowest values of a 2D array c++

Tags: c++

I've decided that i'll find the index of the max and min value and then change it, but i can't find a way to get the index:

```
int findmax(int row, int col, float** arr) {
float max = arr[0][0];
for (int i = 0;i < row;i++) {
    for (int j = 0;j < col;j++) {
        if (arr[i][j] > max) {
            max = arr[i][j];

        }
    }
}
int p=0;
for (int i = 0;i < row;i++) {
    for (int j = 0;j < col;j++) {
        if (arr[i][j] != max) {
            p++;
        }
        else if (arr[i][j]==max){
            break;
        }
    }
  }
  return p;
}
```

The program doesn't stop when the max value is found
It only works when the array has 1 row.

Comment: This code looks like it should work, can you provide some sample inputs, outputs, and desired outputs?

Answer (score 1):

The better way for your 2D array to save pair of indexes for each extreme. You could try next solution:

```
std::pair<int, int> findmax(int row, int col, float** arr) {
    float max = arr[0][0];
    std::pair<int, int> indexes;

    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
            if (arr[i][j] > max) {
                max = arr[i][j];
                indexes = std::make_pair(i, j);
            }
        }
    }

    return indexes;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works we [expected](http://codepad.org/pEc5Ai6T):

```
int findmax(int row, int col, float** arr) {
    float max = arr[0][0];
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
            if (arr[i][j] > max) {
                max = arr[i][j];

            }
        }
    }
    int p = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
            if (arr[i][j] != max) {
                p++;
            }
            else if (arr[i][j] == max) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return p;
}

int main()
{
    float **ppAr;
    ppAr = new float*[2];

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
        ppAr[i] = new float[10];
    }

    ppAr[0][0] = (float)1; //0
    ppAr[0][1] = (float)2; //1
    ppAr[1][0] = (float)4; //2 -> max
    ppAr[1][1] = (float)3;

    return findmax(2, 2, ppAr);

}
```

This one returns 2 .